# Is it obligatory to capitalize the word 'president' before a name (as in 'president Donald Trump')?

Tags: style, capitalization

Gramarly insists on capitalizing: 'President Bill Clinton', 'President Donald Trump', etc. But I don't want to do it. Can I use a regular lowercase 'p'? (with respect, please give me a break from "oooh, it's not about grammar rules, it's about style guides, different style guides tell different things, blah blah blah")

Comment: The tone of your question feels argumentative and confrontational. If this was not your intention, please consider editing it to remove the "give me a break" sentence and perhaps to explain why you "don't want" to capitalize the title. (And if it _was_ your intention, then you might review the guidelines for asking questions on this site.)

Comment: @TypeIA It was direct rather than confrontational. I don't want to capitalize because it doesn't look good. It looks as if 'President' is the first name, 'Donald' is the middle name, and 'Trump' is the last name. I don't like confusing capitalization (I mean, visually confusing; of course, nobody is stupid enough to interpret it the way I described)

Comment: @SergeySolotarev It doesn't look confusing as you described to native speakers. It's quite normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"President" here is being used as a [title](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title), just like [Doctor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_(title)), and as such it must be capitalized per the conventions of written English. The grammar police won't come and arrest you if you don't, but you will be deviating from the convention that everyone else follows and expects.